# search for a config line within a block

Tags: python, ciscoconfparse

I am learning Python module ciscoconfparse to loop thru each interface in the config files and find all interfaces that are configured with switchport mode access.  I parsed the config files with find_blocks method and it outputs the result as expected below. I also want to loop thru each returned interfaces and search for the dot1x pae authenticator line. If it finds, then return the interface name that was configured with dot1x pae authenticator.  I tried the following codes but it didn't work yet.  Please help. thanks

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 10
 dot1x pae authenticator
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 154
 dot1x pae authenticator
```

The code is below:

```
import os
import re
import csv
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
file_exists = os.path.isfile(r'c:\users\lang\documents\result.csv')
if not file_exists:
    with open (r'c:\users\lang\documents\result.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        Header = ['Device', 'Vul ID', 'Exception', 'Status', 'Code', 'Severity', 'Reason']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=Header)
        writer.writeheader()
def check_services():
    configs = (r'C:\Users\Lang\Documents\Tutorials\Python\Scripts\NetworkAudit\Data')

    for config in os.listdir(configs):
        if config.endswith(".txt"):
            filename = os.path.split(config)     #print(filename[1])
            parse = CiscoConfParse(config)
            all_intfs = parse.find_blocks('switchport mode access')
            for intf in all_intfs:
                print(intf)
                dot1x = re.search("^\sdot1x\spae\sauthenticator", all_intfs)
                print(dot1x)
check_services()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get filtered result using following:

```
parse = CiscoConfParse(config)

# Return a list of all interfaces with switchport mode access
mode_access_intfs = parse.find_objects_w_child(r"^interf", r"switchport mode access")

# For each interface above, print out relevant information...
for obj in mode_access_intfs:

    # Find dot1x mode
    has_dotx = obj.re_match_iter_typed(r'^\s*(dot1x pae authenticator).*$', default='')

    if has_dotx:    
      # Print out what we found...
      print("-----")
      print("Object: {0}".format(obj))
      print("  Interface config line: {0}".format(obj.text))
      print("  has dotx mode: {0}".format(has_dotx))
```

Check on replit: https://replit.com/@arvindDhakad/QuickwittedOldlaceSet#main.py

examples: https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/tree/master/examples

Comment: thank you. it worked.  I also tried obj.re_match_iter_typed(r'\s*(dot1 pae authenticator).*$', r'dot1x port-control\s auto.*), default = '') to find if the interface also has the dot1x port-control line, but the re_match_iter_typed didn't accept two arguments.  Can you suggest a way to use multiple search arguments ?

Comment: you can write two different re match. if both matches then print